# Remove vertical scrollbar by auto adjusting height to viewport

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a page in Bootstrap 4. When I added the footer a vertical scrollbar is coming. I don't want the vertical scrollbar. I want the whole page including the footer to adjust within the viewport height. How can I achieve this. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/hn6sq2t7/) is the jsfiddle.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Demo</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="my-1 mx-2 close">X</span>
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">☰</span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link active-link banner __mPS2id"> Home </a>
                  </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link banner __mPS2id"> Menu 1 </a>
                  </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link banner __mPS2id"> Menu 2 </a>
                  </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link  mPS2id-highlight ">Menu 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item admin">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Menu 4</a>
        </li>
                      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer sit amet orci quis erat imperdiet condimentum vel eu sapien. Morbi convallis sapien et molestie finibus. Fusce eleifend vitae orci eget porta. Etiam malesuada facilisis iaculis. Ut tempus, sem quis tincidunt condimentum, risus ligula vestibulum mi, sit amet imperdiet mauris ex id augue. Sed sed dictum velit. Etiam varius elit et odio vulputate, sit amet interdum tellus sagittis. Morbi vulputate leo a dolor consequat tempor. Nam sed auctor nisi. In luctus eleifend laoreet. Morbi id nisl non ex fringilla tincidunt. Suspendisse eget venenatis tortor.

Proin eu consectetur magna. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aenean vehicula imperdiet aliquam. Nam a sem vel est tristique laoreet. Aenean nisl dolor, tempor in iaculis ac, efficitur at lorem. Proin scelerisque ipsum ut sapien luctus, id viverra tellus ornare. Cras lorem tortor, ultricies hendrerit vulputate quis, tincidunt in ipsum. Nam nec dolor dolor. Donec quis felis laoreet, feugiat purus et, imperdiet tortor. Cras non pulvinar leo, nec lobortis mi. Phasellus pellentesque placerat auctor. Suspendisse a urna vel ipsum faucibus hendrerit eget sit amet leo. Etiam consequat ex eget pulvinar pharetra. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam aliquam, tellus nec consequat faucibus, dui felis condimentum nulla, quis elementum massa turpis et felis.
</div>
<div class="footer">
    Ⓒ 2021 All rights reserved T
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you provide live demo?

Comment: @Mangesh       I have shared the jsfiddle.

Comment: Do you want footer to always display at bottom and header at top and middle section to be scrollable?

Comment: No. Only the header is fixed. But in this page I want the height to be auto-adjusted so that the header, content, and footer fit inside the viewport

Comment: Do you want something like this?
https://jsfiddle.net/fu0564qh/

Comment: I don't want the vertical scrollbar in desktop

Comment: But lets say, content is beyond the viewport, then how you will able to show that data?
scrollbar is required

Comment: Are you trying to get the whole thing to scale down when it is too big for the viewport? Or are you wanting the footer to be fixed at the bottom of the viewport and the content to be scrollable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave the height in percentage and was able to solve the problem.

```
.container-fluid{
height: 93%;
}

.footer{
height: 7%;
}
```